# Optimum sql solution for this scenario

Tags: php, sql

I am working on a link shortening script. here is a little what it does:

It checks the link if not shortened already, it shortens it and adds the owner (user) id if logged in, so the user can see it in their dashboards.
But in case if its already shortened it gives out the shortened version.  which prevents the other users who shorten the link to see it in their dashboards. now i want to add a way so who ever shortens it will see it in their dashboards.
There are two possibilities in my mind:

1. Create seperate sql records if the submitter ids are different.
2. Add a field like `new_owners` and it will update with comma seperate username/ids everytime the same link is shortened by different users.

Which is the best option, or if there is another better option ? Which takes less resources and is fast?
cheers

Comment: You need to consider indexing on (Original)URL field, because you are comparing this field on every record entry. This might help increasing performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the easiest and fastest way to realize this is to create a new record each time a link is shortened. Put indices on the shortlink, the link, the id and maybe the user-id.

The benefits:

- Users can see shortened link in their dashboard
- They can remove those links whithout others being disturbed
- fast
- only easy queries

The shortcomings:

- Will use more space since every link is saved a number of times
- Uses additional space for indices

Comment: Thanks Martin i almost forgot this point : They can remove those links whithout others being disturbed . i will go with this solution then :}